# iOS UIWebView lost cookie in the HTML

Tags: ios, cookies, uiwebview

Our project is the shopping-mall, so we need to set up session_key to UIWebView

this is my code to set cookie

```

```
    let url = URL(string: requestUrl)

    var requst = URLRequest(url: url!)

    requst.addValue("user_session=\(YTUserInfo.share.session_key)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Cookie")

    webView.loadRequest(requst)
```

```

When I get into the webpage, php can get my cookie

but when I click 'buy' button, my cookie is lost?

look this picture

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHkgf.jpg

when i click this button , php can't get my session?

so what should I do?

Xcode version : 9.2

mobile : iPhone 6 ,iOS 11.2

iOS Language : Swift 4.0

service Language : PHP

now ,I find the question,
when the UIWebView load new webpage,javaScript can't get my cookie!

Comment: lots answers are there on this webview's cookies topic. maybe help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem

```html
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: 
URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        guard request.allHTTPHeaderFields!["Cookie"] != nil else {
            let urlStr = request.url!.absoluteString
            let url =  URL(string:urlStr)
            var request = URLRequest(url:url!)
            request.addValue("user_session=\(YTUserInfo.share.session_key)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Cookie")
            
            webView.loadRequest(request)
            return true
        }
        
        return true
    }
```

But When Web started a AJAX request, web still couldn't get cookie

I solved this problem "When Web started a AJAX request, web still couldn't get cookie"

```html
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        
        let cookieStr = "user_session=\(YTUserInfo.share.session_key)"
        let source = "document.cookie = '\(cookieStr);path=/';"
        webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: source)
    }
```

have fun

Comment: Does ur AJAX request able to trigger this delegate function?

Comment: @TonyFungChoiFung No, AJAX request does not trigger this delegate, and this function is to load a new page to be executed

Comment: yep. I think so. For those request made by javascript, you may need to..
1. call the JS function from the iOS client to pass the information (e.g. session key) 
2. handle the key manually in JS to append in request. 

You can reference this article (as i believe u a Chinese u should able to read it)

http://www.cnblogs.com/zhuqil/archive/2011/08/03/2126562.html

p.s. UIWebView is now deprecated, u better to switch to WKWebView if you have time

Comment: @TonyFungChoiFung You are Chinese?

Comment: umm u can say so. I come from Hong Kong. Is the issue resolved yet?

Answer (score 0):

Try to using `HTTPCookieStorage` to store cookie. Code example maybe help:

```
let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: [
        .name: "user_session",
        .value: YTUserInfo.share.session_key,
        .path: "/",
        .domain: "your-domain.com"])
HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookie!)
```

Comment: I also used this method , but it was still the same. when the webView jump to other page,javascript can't get my cookie

Comment: @Jeff.Chen Is your web page using the same domain? Or try to set expiration date to your cookie.

Comment: yes,web page is using the same domain,and I'm set the expiration date to one year. But still like this T_T

Comment: @Jeff.Chen Interesting. Can’t get value using document.cookie? Using Safari Web Inspector to debug for more infos.